Does block verification for OTA updates for Magisk apply to LineageOS?
In the Ota Upgrade Guide from Magisk, it says:

NOTE: In order to apply OTAs, you HAVE to make sure you haven’t modified and read-only partitions yourself (such as /system or /vendor) in any way. Even remounting the partition to rw will tamper block verification!!

The guide does not elaborate on this further. It sounds like this is the case for stock ROMs, but it does not say. I use LineageOS, which is an A/B partition scheme.
